# Update a json file using csv file contents

Tags: json, shell, csv, jq

I've 2 files: changes.csv and sample.json. My csv file is like following:

```
header "a", "b"
      "a11","b1"
      "a22","b2"
      "a33","b3"
```

and the json file is like:

```
[
 {"a":"a1","b":"b1"},
 {"a":"a2","b":"b2"},
 {"a":"a3","b":"b3"},
 {"a":"a4","b":"b4"}
]
```

I need to write a jq command, which make changes in json file using the csv file, i.e., the final output of the json file should be like following:

```
[
 {"a":"a11","b":"b1"},
 {"a":"a22","b":"b2"},
 {"a":"a33","b":"b3"},
 {"a":"a4","b":"b4"}
]
```

I wrote the following command:

```
while IFS=",", read f1 f2
do
  jq --argjson k1 $f1 --argjson k2 $f2 '(.[] | select(.b == $k2) | .a) |= $k1' sample.json| sponge sample.json
done < changes.csv
```

Although, for each iteration it is able to filter and update the value of key "a", but when I try to sponge the results into the json file, it is unable to do so. Don't know where exactly I am missing out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just figured it out that if I transform my csv file values into input readable format and use --arg instead of --argjson, the file gets update fine. So, the command `awk '{gsub(/"/,"")};1' b.csv > c.csv` will convert the csv file into:

```
a11,b1
a22,b2
a33,b3
```

So, now if apply the command:

```
while IFS=",", read f1 f2
do
  jq --arg k1 $f1 --arg k2 $f2 '(.[] | select(.b == $k2) | .a) |= $k1' sample.json| sponge sample.json
done < c.csv
```

the desired changes will take place.

The plausible reason why it failed in older format because when we read values using "read" command, it transforms `"a"` to `"\"a\""`. So, each time I append the answer, it returns void answer.

The answer works with any type of json format. For example, if json object is like:

```
[
 { 
  "d": { "a":"a1", "c":"c1"},
  "b": "b1"
  }
]
```

we can update the command to `'(.[] | select(.b == $k2) | .d.a) |= $k1'`.

I didn't try the other methods posted, but I appreciate for the help.
Thanks folks (@peak & @Fravadona)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the CSV is reasonably well-behaved, you could write:

```
# Skip the CSV header row by NOT specifying the -n option
< changes.csv | jq -Rcr --argfile json sample.json '
  def trim: sub("^[ \t]*\""; "") | sub("\"[ \t]*$";"");
  INDEX(inputs | split(",") | map(trim) | select(length>0); .[1]) as $dict
  | $json
  | map( .a = $dict[.b][0] )
'
```

For more messy CSV, you will probably want to use a CSV-to-JSON or CSV-to-TSV tool (which can both quite easily be written in jq -- see e.g. https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Convert_CSV_records_to_TSV#jq)

---

If you prefer not to use the --argfile option, then by all means use some other method of reading the two files, e.g. you could use --rawfile for the CSV, leaving STDIN for the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

For a pure `jq` solution, you'll better make sure that your CSV doesn't contain any `,` or `"` or `\n` in any field or else the code will become a lot more complex.

Hence, I propose a solution with [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) (available [here](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller/releases) for several OSs), which can do the task easily and robustly:

```bash
mlr --icsv --ojson --no-jvstack join --ijson -f file.json -j 'b' --ul file.csv
```

```json
[
{"b": "b1", "a": "a11"},
{"b": "b2", "a": "a22"},
{"b": "b3", "a": "a33"}
]
```

Let's decompose the command:

- ```bash
  mlr join -f file1 -j 'b' file2
  ```

  will join *file1* and *file2* on the field `b`. When an other field than `b` exists in **both** files (for ex. `a`) then it is the value of *file2* that is outputted.

  So, for updating the JSON with the values in the CSV, *file1* shall be the JSON and *file2* the CSV.
- `--ul` means to output the unjoinable lines of *file1*; without it, the output will only contain the records that have been "paired".
- With the `join` verb, Miller allows to specify a different **input format** for *file1* than the one of *file2*; you set the default input format as `--icsv` (for handling *file2*) and override it with `--ijson` after the `join` verb (for handling *file1*).
- The **output format** is set to JSON with `--ojson`. The `--no-jvstack` means to output one "record" per line.